# How to Register the component correctly without Error? Vue Js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am get this error due import of folder that contain index file,how can I solve it?

```
Root folder
.app.js
.store
..index.js

import store from './store/index'
   Vue.component('posts', require('./components/Posts.vue'))
    Vue.component('createPost', require('./components/CreatePost.vue'))

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store
});
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <create-post> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option

Answer (score 0):

You registered the component incorrectly, as it stated.

Change these

```
Vue.component('createPost', require('./components/CreatePost.vue'))
```

To these

```
Vue.component('create-post', require('./components/CreatePost.vue'))
```

Comment: [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in <CreatePost> <Root>

Comment: @JaneJohn update your question and put the codes of **CreatePost.vue**

Comment: thank you all,the error was caused by camel character.